# ggplot2 does not seem to properly center points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

First post here.

I am working on a visualization process that is seeking to compare past and present measurements for the same individual. I have used the `mtcars` data frame to illustrate a similar thinking. Considering `mpg2` as perhaps the next year's model's MPG, I created it using a random increase from the `mpg` variable.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$mpg2 <- mtcars$mpg + sample(c(0,1),length(mtcars$mpg), replace = T)

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
 geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y =  rownames(mtcars) ), col = 'red', size = 2) + 
 geom_point(aes(x = mpg2,y =  rownames(mtcars)), col = 'darkgreen', size = 1)
```

[image]

It looks fine for all intents and purposes, but it really bothers me that the tiny point (current mpg) is not directly centered in the larger point (last year's mpg). Has anyone encountered this issue/found an effective workaround?

Comment: This is just an issue with the way the default R graphics device renders the image. If you run `ggsave("mtcars_test.svg")`, the resulting file should have the dots centered.

Comment: I tested your code (on macOS 10.13.6 and R 3.4.3) and found that the overlapping points look quite well centered on each other. Results were the same using the quartz device, or png with `ggsave("test.png", height=3.5, width=5.5, units="in", dpi=200)`.